# Redshift - Split_Part and minimum value

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a list of dates in a column in Redshift table t1 as follows:

```
dates
2020-10-25,2020-10-26,2020-10-23,2020-10-24,2020-10-25,2020-10-24,2020-10-24,2020-10-24
2020-10-25,2020-10-26,2020-10-23,2020-10-24,2020-10-25
```

While selecting data, I want to add a field earliest_date = MIN of all the dates appearing in the column dates. I tried using split_part but it needs a 'n' i.e. location of the date which will vary from row to row.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Redshift doesn't support ARRAY operators and functions - see [Unsupported PostgreSQL functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)

Comment: can you tell max number of dates that a record in column dates can contain?

Comment: max numbers would be 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up using a UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION min_date (po_datelist varchar) RETURNS varchar IMMUTABLE as $$
    
    def min_date(po_datelist):
        x=min(po_datelist.split(','))
        if x=='':
            return None
        else:
            return x
    return min_date(po_datelist)
        
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table numtable (id int) 

insert into numtable values (1) ,(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),
(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18)


select max(to_date(datestr,'yyyy-mm-dd'))
from
(
select id, split_part ('2020-10-25,2020-10-26,2020-10-23,2020-10-24,2020-10-25,2020-10-24,2020-10-24,2020-10-24
2020-10-25,2020-10-26,2020-10-23,2020-10-24,2020-10-25',',',id) datestr
from numtable
)
a
```